# What's the difference between sv_catpv() and sv_catpvs()?

Tags: perl, xs

According to [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#SV-Body-Allocation), `sv_catpv()` works as follows:

> Concatenates the `NUL`-terminated string onto the end of the string which is in the SV. If the SV has the UTF-8 status set, then the bytes appended should be valid UTF-8. Handles 'get' magic, but not 'set' magic.
>
> `void sv_catpv(SV *const sv, const char* ptr)`

Most of the XS tutorials I've found use `sv_catpvs()`, though, which does this:

> Like `sv_catpvn`, but takes a literal string instead of a string/length pair.
>
> `void sv_catpvs(SV* sv, const char* s)`

Well, that's not very helpful, so let's look at `sv_catpvn()`:

> Concatenates the string onto the end of the string which is in the SV. The `len` indicates number of bytes to copy. If the SV has the UTF-8 status set, then the bytes appended should be valid UTF-8. Handles 'get' magic, but not 'set' magic.
>
> `void sv_catpvn(SV *dsv, const char *sstr, STRLEN len)`

So, `sv_catpvn` does the same thing as `sv_catpv` except that it takes the string length as a separate parameter, and `sv_catpvs` is the same as `sv_catpvn` except it takes the literal string.

Is there some subtle difference between `sv_catpv` and `sv_catpvs` that I'm missing, or are they just two ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the passages you quoted, `sv_catpvs` only takes a string literal.

```
const char *str = "foo";

sv_catpvs(sv, "foo");   // ok
sv_catpvs(sv, str);     // ERROR
```

`sv_catpv`, on the other hand, accepts any expression that returns a string.

```
sv_catpv(sv, "foo");    // ok
sv_catpv(sv, str);      // ok
```

So why does `sv_catpvs` exist at all? Because it's faster. The reason `sv_catpvs` takes only takes a string literal is that it's a macro that expands

```
sv_catpvs(sv, "foo")
```

into something similar to

```
sv_catpvn_flags(sv, "foo", sizeof("foo")-1, SV_GMAGIC)
```

which resolves to

```
sv_catpvn_flags(sv, "foo", 3, SV_GMAGIC)
```

at compile-time. `sv_catpv`, on the other hand, is forced to use slower `strlen`.

Comment: which means sv_catpvs can actually include null characters